# PHP 5.3 with java Integration

Tags: php

Iam very new to PHP.
I am usingPHP 5.3 version with Apache 2.2.25.
I was successfully able to acccess java libraries by starting javaBridge.jar.

I am facing issues while using a java class file in PHP Script, I am getting the foll error:

```
hi Warning: Unknown: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'Asia/Kolkata' for '5.5/no DST' instead in Unknown on line 0 Fatal error: Uncaught [[o:Exception]:"java.lang.Exception: CreateInstance failed: new PrintHello. Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PrintHello VM: 1.6.0_26@http://java.sun.com/" at: #-17 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) #-16 java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) #-15 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) #-14 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) #-13 sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) #-12 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) #-11 java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) #-10 java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) #-9 php.java.bridge.Util.classForName(Util.java:1518) #-8 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.CreateObject(JavaBridge.java:445) #-7 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequest(Request.java:458) #-6 php.java.bridge.Request.handleRequests(Request.java:500) #-5 php.java.bridge.JavaBridge.handleRequests(JavaBridge.java:150) #-4 php.java.bridge.JavaBridgeRunner.doPut(JavaBridgeRunner.java:207) #-3 php.java.bridge.http.HttpServer.servi in http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc on line 195
```

I have placed the java class file in htdocs folder and modified the php.ini file with foll lines

```
java.java_home = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin"
java.java ="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre"
java.class.path = "c:\PHP\ext\JavaBridge.jar;c:\myclasses"
java.library  = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
java.library.path = "c:\PHP\ext" 
 extensions = php_java.dll
```

But I am still not able to access the java class file through foll PHP script

```
<?php 
  require_once("http://127.0.0:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
  echo "hi";
$ obj = new java("PrintHello"); 
echo $ obj->printHello("Hi ");
?>
```

1. can I invoke the java class file through PHP 5.3 script ,
2. I need to import the jar file , java_require or java_autoload doesnt work.

Any suggestions or documents related to the same.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once("http://127.0.0:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
```

replace by real localhost ip 127.0.0.1:

```
require_once("http://127.0.0.1:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc");
```

And please don't put a blankspace between variable and dollar char `$obj`

Comment: Thats not the problem. PHP is able to find the include

Answer (score 0):

I have never used javabridge (never heard about it either), but for the warning you are getting:

This a very typical error, that is caused by not having a timezone specified in your php.ini. The location of php.ini is usually /etc/php/php.ini in a linux system. Open it and search for the line:

```
date.timezone =
```

Fill in your timezone there (if you have no such line, write it), the possible list of timezones are located here:

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php